# How to execute several functions in random order?

Tags: python, function, random

I have defined four functions. These functions return the same varables but have different parameters.

Here is a simple example:

```
def func1(studentID, homework1, T1, score):
    if len(homework1) > T1:
        score[studentID] = 1
    else:
        score[studentID] = 0
    return score

def func2(studentID, homework2, T2, attendance, score):
    if len(homework2) > T2 and attendance == 1:
        score[studentID] = 1
    else:
        score[studentID] = 0
    return score
```

Now I need to execute these functions in a random order, i.e., sometimes func1 firstly and func2 secondly, but sometimes otherwise. I only know how to do that without parameters and returns as following:

```
import random
functions = [func1, func2]
random.shuffle(functions)
for i in functions:
    i()
```

But have no idea how to do it with parameters and returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambdas to bind parameters:

```
import random
param1 = 123
param2 = 456
functions = [lambda : func1(param1), lambda : func2(param2)]
random.shuffle(functions)
results = [ i() for i in functions ]
```

Comment: Thanks kutschkem. But I still don't understand how to pass the parameters and get the returns. Could you pls give me more details?

Comment: @JohnBear I fixed it. I think it is reasonable to just collect the results in a list.

Answer (score 0):

you could make a list of params that each index is correlated to the function list or define dictionary which would be more convenient

```py
import random
# define argument lists
params_list1 = [1, "a", [1,2,3]]
params_list2 = ["b", "a"]

# dictionary answer
dictionary = {'func1':[func1,params_list1], 'func2':[func2,param_list2]}
for f, params in random.shuffle(dictionary.values()):
    f(*params)
```